# Waiting for AsyncStorage.getItem()

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am using `AsyncStorage` in my React Native application to store information about the user. The `getItem()` function is asynchronous and requires me to implement a callback when I want to load data from the storage system.

```js
AsyncStorage.getItem("phoneNumber").then((value) => {
    this.setState({"phoneNumber": value});
}).done();
```

Because retrieving a value from the storage does not take long, I would like to wait until the operation is complete before continuing execution.

Is it possible to load data in a way that is not Asynchronous? If not, is there an easy way for me to wait until the `getItem()` call is complete to continue executing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can try either add a then after your `getItem`.

```js
AsyncStorage.getItem("phoneNumber").then((value) => {
    this.setState({"phoneNumber": value});
})
.then(res => {
    //do something else
});
```

Or use await to wait the `async` operation to finish

```js
var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
//use value to do something else.
```

Comment: Syntax Error: Await is a reserved word.

Comment: Add 'async' keyword to the function definition of the function using 'await'

Comment: Where to call this on page load?

Comment: You need to call it inside an async function

Comment: I am also doing the same with await. After `var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);` nothing is happening. Its not returning anything.

Comment: It is not returning anything because of [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12830) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14101).

Comment: For an example below:
myfunction = async () => {
 try {
  let value = AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
 }
}
But, I'm getting this error: { [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_asyncStorage.AsyncStorage.getItem')]
How do we fix this?

Comment: `TypeError: bundle.added is undefined`

Comment: Was able to fix this issue. Remove curly braces from the import statement of AsyncStorage and it works. But, it's really weird.  
`import { AsyncStorage } from '@react-native-community/async-storage';` - doesn't work.  
But `import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';` - works fine

Answer (score 6):

try this option and you will not get the

> Syntax Error: Await is a reserved word

```js
async getData() {
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem("@App:KEY");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
async getPhoneNumber() {
  const phoneNumber = await AsyncStorage.getItem("phoneNumber")
  console.log(phoneNumber)
}
```