# How can i assign token in async storage to headers in app.js after login. in react-native

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client, asyncstorage, request-headers

**I am getting access token after login and I want to assign that token to authorization in headers in my App.js
I am using async storage to store the access token in local storage and I want to assign to headers in my App.js file How can I do it. I want to assign token to authorization in headers so that I can make graphql API calls**

*MY App.js file*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Navigator from "@Navigation"
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-boost';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://graphql.sample.com/graphql',
});

const token = AsyncStorage.getItem('@accessToken')

 const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ,
      }
    }
});

const link = authLink.concat(httpLink)

const cache = new InMemoryCache();

const defaultOptions = {
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    errorPolicy: "all"
  }
};

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  defaultOptions
});
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <Navigator/>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
});
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the authLink function to work with async/await worked for me! Hope this helps;

```js
const authLink = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
    // get the authentication token from async storage if it exists
    const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@accessToken');

    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: accessToken ? `Bearer ${accessToken}` : '',
        },
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should await `AsyncStorage.getItem('@accessToken')` to get your accessToken before passing it to `authorization: token`. This is a post relating to [`Waiting for AsyncStorage.getItem()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120305/waiting-for-asyncstorage-getitem)  in React Native.
Try this:

```js
...
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@accessToken')

 const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token ,
      }
    }
});

...
```

Comment: not able to get value from AsyncStorage when we assign to const token